# Is it possible to change the target folder of a WordPress plugin during an automatic install?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need you help. I'm currently trying to install a custom plugin from my GitLab repository via the plugins api in WordPress:

```
public function filter_plugins_api( $result, string $action, object $args ) {
        $download_url = 'https://gitlab.xxx.de/xxx-development/xxx-helper/-/archive/1.0.0/xxx-helper-1.0.0.zip';

        if ( $action !== 'plugin_information' || $result !== false || ! isset( $args->slug ) || $args->slug !== 'xxx-helper' ) {
            return $result;
        }

        $result                = new stdClass();
        $result->name          = esc_html__( 'XXX Helper', 'xxx' );
        $result->version       = '1.0.0';
        $result->download_link = esc_url( $download_url );

        return $result;
    }
```

This works really well but the problem is that the plugins folder name is `xxx-helper-1.0.0` after the installation is done which breaks the whole plugin functionality like dependency checks for example:

`...../wp-content/plugins/xxx-helper-1.0.0`

My first thought was to change the versioning in GitLab but I can't find anything about that so I've created two question about this idea already in the GitLab forum and on StackOverflow.

But now I have another idea. If I can't change the filename on GitLab, can I may change it during the plugin installation for the plugin folder?

I've also found nothing about that so hopefully someone did this already and can tell me if this is possible or not?

I think it might be easier to change something in my code than in GitLab but we'll see.

Thanks and hopefully we can find a way so that I can hold my deadline...